# How can i change Galleria image gallery info button effect show or hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Galleria image gallery jQuery plugin.
How can i change gallery info button show hide smoothly or with fade effect.

Please refer this url 
http://photography.freewebsitehostingusa.com/?page_id=13
In image gallery at top a plus(+), when click on it shows. but not smoothly.
Is there any way to change this show hide effect in galleria plugin.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change the following in `galleria-classic.js`:

```
// toggle info
if ( options._toggle_info ) {
    info.bind( click, function() {
        info.toggle(); // change to -> info.toggle("fast");
    });
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Note, this won't fade, but might make it look a bit nicer than simply just showing up and disappearing.

Comment: If it works, and you used my answer, would you mind just marking my answer above as the solution? Thanks